# Do I have to use Parallel Routes in Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

guys,

I recently started to study Nextjs v13, but I got a simple question.
I read the doc and it says it is used for showing one or more pages in the same layout.
Can we not just make a folder called components and make two (or more) components inside the folder and import and use them on a page, so we can feel like two pages are shown on the page?
and also for each component, we can wrap it with suspense (streaming), so whatever can be shown first, it will be shown first and the rest will be shown when data is completely loaded.

what will be main advantages of using Parallel Routes in nextjs?

Comment: Hi. Did you figure this out? The docs do not make it clear how "Parallel Routes" differ from just using normal separate components with Suspense boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used it on a project because I had to use the searchParam prop.

Had 2 sections: (i) a form that updates the searchParam in the url and (ii) a list of results that uses the searchParam value, fetches data based on it and display results

Without the parallel layout, the browser url was only updating once the second block had loaded, which I didn't like e.g. if the user refreshes during the loading.

Beside that, I like being able to use the loading.js and the error.js pattern, even if I could replicate that without parallel routing.

Had a few issues but looks like they are being fixed (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49243 and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51951)